# Are Gnosis rolls made with Permanent or Temporary Gnosis?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse

My GM and I are confused about whether you roll your Permanent or Temporary Gnosis when making a Gnosis Roll. What is the proper choice, and what pages specify it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a lot more complicated to find a book answer than I thought it would. In the end on page 126, you'll see it reference the "pool" and the "rating". You always roll your rating in a dice pool. The pool is how many points you have. On page 171, they also reference how many dice you can roll for "ratings" that go above 5 (Such as Willpower, Rage, and Gnosis).

This is out of Werewolf the Apocalypse's Revised core book.

Comment: It holds true for all of the world of darkness games where the names are similar for permanent and temporary stats (demon had the same problem with temporary and permanent faith and even for its humanity trait). Wish they were a bit more creative back then naming power stats and energy stats differently from each other.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you use the permanent gnosis.

> **When rolling Rage, Gnosis or Willpower, do you roll temporary or permanent ratings?**
>
> Usually permanent, although some Storytellers prefer temporary. Either way is fine. The exception is Rage; you always roll temporary or permanent, whichever is *higher*.

This is answered in the Errata from the Storyteller's Handbook of Werewolf of 2002, page 21.